# Laravel with WAMP server -error, NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Tags: php, laravel

I am starting with learning laravel I have a problem when I want to navigate between sites in my actions folder this is my code sample within home.blade.php:

```
@extends('layout.master')
@section('content')
<div class="content">
    <a href="{{ route('greet') }}">Greet</a>
    <a href="{{ route('hug') }}">Hug</a>
    <a href="{{ route('kiss') }}">Kiss</a>
</div>
@endsection
```

My master.blade.php looks like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::to('css/main.css')}}">
    @yield('styles')
</head>
<body>
    @include('include.header');
    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My routes.php looks like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Route::get('/greet', function () {
    return view('actions.greet');
})->name('greet');


Route::get('/hug', function () {
    return view('actions.hug');
})->name('hug');

Route::get('/kiss', function () {
    return view('actions.kiss');
})->name('kiss');
```

I want to navigate to the actions folder which contains my files, everything works great till I start trying this example with routing?

error:

```
    in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Comment: Can you post whole stack trace please?

Comment: What is the URL of your request? This Laravel error means the URL doesn't match any of the defined routes.

Comment: @Matey I am totally new to laravel my URL is ´http://localhost/laravel/greet´

Comment: does http://localhost/laravel show you the 'home' view successfully ?

Comment: Yes it shows my home view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you try this?

```
Route::get('/kiss', ['as' => 'kiss', function () {
   return view('actions.kiss');
}]);
```

And the URL

```
  $url = route('kiss');
  return redirect()->route('kiss');
```

Comment: {{ URL::route(‘kiss’) }} or {{ URL::to(‘kiss’) }}

Comment: And maybe try to put your route in a Route::group

Comment: Well actually i copy all your routes in a new project with laravel and works fine... actions directory is inside views directory?? resources/views/actions/kiss.blade.php

Comment: Yes it is inside the view directory but it doesnt work with me I made this as project in my wamp/www/ I don't use blog50 or c9 ?

Comment: Can you try **php artisan route:list** in your console and check if the route really exists?

Comment: And try this too **php artisan serve**.. and use the locahost:8000 or you can configure a vHost -> **DocumentRoot  /var/www/yourproject/public/** and your **Servername dev.yourprojectname**

Comment: It said to me could not open input file artisan when I insert this into my console

Comment: You need to be inside your laravel projecto to execute the artisan command

Comment: hey i did it and I got some table with method whic is get and with URI with /, and my tree routes

Comment: you should get something like this If you route hug exists METHOD|URI|NAME|ACTION|MIDDLEWARE **GET|HEAD | hug  | hug  | Closure | web**

Comment: Yes I got it like that

Comment: ok now try to use php artisan serve and use locahost:port in my case when i get locahost:8000

Comment: I used php artisan serve and I got it Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/

Comment: Man it work can you explain me why I did this php artisan serve

Comment: Well for me it's like a vHost that gives you **DocumentRoot /var/www/yourproject/public/** and provides you a host

Comment: if you are using in linux try this http://localhost/baselaravel/public/index.php/hug and if you are in windows http://localhost/baselaravel/public/hug

Comment: really happy for you :)